# CiviEvent with Sub-events and Conference Slots - how to....?

Tags: civievent, registration

I cannot find any good instructions on how to create sub-events.  Basically I want to create a master/parent event that has 1 or 2 sub-events.  I have found a few links about Conference Slots and have spent a day trying to work out how to use hem with no luck - any hints?
Can it only be used with paid events because it is a shopping cart thing?
Does it only work with online registrations?
Can a staff member register a participant manually or does it only work with the online registration page?

Note that I'm using WordPress so the web-forms thing with Drupal is not an option.

thanks!

Comment: Time goes by: How did you accomplished subevents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub-events and Conference Slots seem to be part of the Event Cart functionality.  There is some documentation here: [CiviEvent Cart Checkout](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviEvent+Cart+Checkout)

That page needs updating since [CRM-8705](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-8705) referenced there was closed in 4.2.  New features were added in 4.7.10 - see [CRM-16481](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16481)  You may need to experiment and/or read the code to figure out exactly what is available.

From [this comment](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16753?focusedCommentId=75839&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-75839) of June 2015, the cart functionality wasn't regarded as supported by the core team even though it is in core.  This might be a candidate for migrating to an extension.  Anyone from core team care to comment on how the event cart functionality is regarded now?

Event Cart is one of the less travelled roads in Civi so proceed with caution.  If you can update and improve the wiki page that would help others.

Comment: I think I'll not progress down the sub-event path any further.  Seems a little clunky to have to create an event, then repeat the process for each stream.  I'm also guessing that I won;t be available to save a template that includes the sub-events meaning that I'll have recreate them every time I have an event of the same type. Would be easier if I could create the parent event first and then while within the parent add/define child events, and then save this as a template.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating Parent Event and Sub Event** - using conference Slot

- Create an Event and consider that as an parent Event - you need to enable  online registration for parent event
- create another event consider this as a sub-event - In conference slot link the parent event and also create a slot and add to the slot - you don't need online registration for sub-event
- repeat the above step to create one more sub-event

Now you can use event info page from parent event and try to book the event - It should create all the three event against the register contact

---

**Regarding Paid Event**

I am not sure about booking an un-paid event - I will give a quick test and will let you know

---

**Regarding Off-line Registration**

To my knowledge - Conference Slot works can only be used for online registration screen

I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Many thanks. I'll test this some more tomorrow and let you know how i go.  Do you know if sub-events can be reported upon seperately per chance?!

Comment: sorry can you please explain the above in details ?

Comment: I'm thinking of trying something like this. Wondering how this attempt turned out @jkobier

Answer (score 1):

We have done some work on an [extension](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.multipleeventreg) which gives a UI as a custom event field where you can select the 'other' events that should be registered for along with the parent one. Works eg for a Series where you want user registered for each event separately, but for a single fee, but eg then allows for flexibility of recording that participant didn't show up on Week 3 Monday series and instead took a spare spot on the Week 3 Thursday series so they didn't miss out on a week.