# Is there a way to make some events a sub-category for another event?

Tags: civievent

I'm trying to figure out how to categorize some events under a sort of "mother" event so that you can only register for the child events if you have registered for the mother event. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This looks like a good question but it would be helpful if you could provide a bit more detail about exactly what you are trying to do.  This will help people to provide more useful answers.  It would also be helpful if you could provide the version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. Drupal, WordPress or Joomla).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-additional-signup

This will register users for additional events automatically when they select specific price set options.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-additional-signup

And then you can also find good answers here: [CiviEvent with Sub-events and Conference Slots - how to....?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16052/civievent-with-sub-events-and-conference-slots-how-to)