# Event on several different days

Tags: wordpress, dates, repeating-events, date-range

I want to create an event in CiviCRM: The event takes place on *8.10., 9.10. and 16.10.* So this is an event with three sessions (not an repeating single event). The participants can not book a session individually, therefore they should only register once and they pay a single fee for all three sessions. In CiviCRM I can only create an event that *starts on 8.10. and lasts until 16.10.* (although there will be no session from 10.10. to 15.10.).

I would like the three listed dates to appear separately in the calendar and on the overview page.

For Drupal I found the plugin *”CiviCRM Multiday Event“* which allows you to do that (https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_multiday_event). But I’m running CiviCRM 5.25.0 on WordPress 5.4.2.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get there?

Thanks a lot for your help!
Michael

Comment: Can you please edit your question to indicate what plugin/extension you're using to generate your calendar?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! Currently I do not have a plugin/extension in use to generate an individual calendar. I use the standard iCal-Link (https://domain.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fical&reset=1&list=1).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think what you need is possible using the built-in iCal feed and a single event - not without writing an extension.

However, perhaps @petednz-fuzion can chime in on the status of his [yet-to-be-published extension](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/37617/12) which I think will meet your needs.  You could create three events, use the extension to ensure that there's a single registration for all three, then your iCal feed should be accurate.

The manual equivalent of this would be to create three events, but only expose the registration for the first one.  When registration closes, use a search to find and add the registrants to the second and third events.  This is actually pretty workable when there's only three days in the series - but pretty tedious when there are 12, so hopefully Pete's extension is almost ready to publish :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! The event would now appear correctly in iCal. Unfortunately, only the date of the first session would appear on the registration page and in the email confirmation. This could cause irritation for participants.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate I feel you can create price sets that shows price field for each date (Label?). And tweak the calendar plugin to use price field to show event on three different dates

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this workaround would not have occurred to me. It would be practicable if one single person would take care of the events. But in this case several people should enter the data. I’m afraid that your solution would then not work smoothly.